# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource and JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, jwt

I am working on a web-based app with angular and spring boot. Jwt is generated and the user can log in but when I want to get user information after login it shows this error on the browser:

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/user/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

And in IntelliJ it says:
**JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String**

What should I do?

Comment: Did you enable CORS? If not, do it and add the URL to the origin. Here's a guide how to do it in Spring Boot https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors. Did you check if your JWT is correct? Please check your implementation how you configured your JWT.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to enable Cross-origin Reference Sharing in Spring Security would be:

In your web security configuration class (annotated with `@EnableWebSecurity`), you need to first enable CORS on the `HttpSecurity` object:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
    ...

}
```

Then add a `@Bean` annotated method in the same class which sets some configurations (like allowed origins and response headers) and returns `CorsConfigurationSource`:

```
@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();

    config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
    config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PUT", "PATCH"));
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));

    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

    return source;
}
```

Regarding "JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String", you need to send `Bearer` along with JWT token(space-separated) in the request `Authorization` header:

`Authorization: Bearer xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz`

Comment: The CorsConfigurationSource method helped me to fix the error. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
```

Over your controller to work with different localhost

Answer (score -4):

You need to check that if the api is up and running on your local.

```
http://localhost:8080/api/user/
```

You also need to check if this **cross origin** is enabled for this api.

There is one chrome extension that is [Allow cors](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en). Add this extension to your browser and it will allow the cors on your local.